# Storing templates using dictionary in c#

Tags: c#-3.0

I have to store some templates based on the statecode.I cannot store them in database. So i thought of creating a dictionary with statecode as key and list as value. I have chosen a list because i need a template line by line.So each string in list is a line. Is there any better way of dealing with this kind of situation. Please comment.

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, List<string>> NotaryForStates = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
    {
        {"AR",new List<string> {"Per Steve Hollowell, ESQ from the Legal Division of the AR, SOS. Telephone number for the Legal Division of the SOS: (501)-682-3012. Arkansas Code 16-47-101.", "State of Arkansas", "County of <notary county>","On this day, <sign date> before me, <name of notary>, the undersigned notary, personally appeared, <name of signer> who acknowledged he/she is the <title of signer> of <name of company> and that he/she as such <title of signer>, being authorized so to do, executed the foregoing instrument for the purposes therein contained, by signing the name of the corporation by himself/herself as <title of signer>.","In witness whereof I hereunto set my hand and official seal.","______________________","Notary Public","<Notary name>","My Commission expires: <notary commission date>"}},
        {"CA",new List<string>{"State of California","County of <Notary County>","On <sign date> before me, <Notary Name>, Notary Public, personally appeared <Signing Party Name>, who proved to me on the basis of satisfactory evidence to be the person(s) whose name is subscribed to the within instrument and acknowledged to me that he/she executed the same in his/her authorized capacity, and that by his/her signature on the instrument the person, or the entity upon behalf of which the person acted, executed the instrument.","I certify under PENALTY OF PERJURY under the laws of the State of California that the foregoing paragraph is true and correct.","WITNESS my hand and official seal.","______________________________","Notary Public: «NotaryName»","My Comm. Expires: «NotaryCommExp»"}},
        {"FL",new List<string>{"State of Florida","County of <Notary County>","On <sign date> before me, the undersigned, a Notary Public, for said County and State, personally appeared  <Signing Party Name>,  personally known to me to be the person that executed the foregoing instrument and acknowledged that is a <signer title> of <name of company>  and that he/she did execute the foregoing instrument.   <Name of Signer> is personally known to me.","_____________________","Notary Public: «NotaryName»","My Comm. Expires: «NotaryCommExp»"}}
    };
```

Comment: @Rohit you can also pick template from a file. The advantage will be in case of small change in template, you don't need to update code.

Answer (score 0):

First alternative: You may use a simple string instead of a list and separate the individual lines with `Environment.NewLine` ("\n"). You can create such strings easily with a `StringBuilder` object and split it again (if you need to) with the `string.Split()` method. This is also (slightly) faster than the `List<string>` approach.

Second alternative: You may use files and store only the filename in your dictionary.

Whether or not one of the above options is a better alternative to your original approach, depends on the concrete project you're working on. All in all, the `List<string>` approach might well be ok...

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use resource files (which are commonly used for localization). Resource files provide a location for storing text or other types of objects which can be used across a Web site, WPF or Windows Forms application, thus creating a central location for maintaining the text. Using resource files can also simplify maintenance of your application.